Python: Only 2 unique column names in dataframe, 3105 columns total. How to get average of row, grouped by unique column name
My dataframe
My dataframe is in the linked image. Basically to make it simple, my dataframe currently looks something like this:



Gene
Cell_A
Cell_B
Cell_B
Cell_B
Cell_A




Gene_A
0
4
35.5
4.5
3.5


Gene_B
1.3
52
3.4
2.4
0


Gene_C
2.3
3.3
32
0
2



And there are 3105 columns of Cell_A and Cell_B combined. There are around 13k (I think?) rows of genes. What I want to do is get the average number per gene (row), grouped by the unique column name. So in the end I would have just 2 columns, Cell_A and Cell_B, with the average number (per gene, i.e. row) as data.
I expect that it has to do something with either agg or groupby. But I have no idea where to even start with this. If you can offer some guidance I would be very grateful!

You are right, you want to group by columns and do the mean operation.
First, preserve the first column as an index:
df = df.set_index(['Gene']) 

Then do
df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).mean()


You shouldn't use the axis=1 option for .groupby anymore, it's deprecated. Instead: df.set_index("Gene").T.groupby(level=0).mean().T.

Thank you so much, it did exactly what I wanted it to do!  Timus is right tho, axis=1 is deprecated, I got a warning message for it but the function still worked

Oh good to know about depreciation.

You're right, groupby() is appropriate here. I have a pattern like this, I think it will work for you:

Ensure we have a row identifier (gene).
Melt the data into a long format with columns "Gene", "Cell_Type", and "Value".
Then calculate the average value for each gene grouped by unique column names.

In code, it goes something like this:
# Melting the DataFrame into long format
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Gene'], var_name='Cell_Type', value_name='Value')

# Standardizing cell types (e.g., "Cell_B1" and "Cell_B2" to just "Cell_B")
df_melted['Cell_Type'] = df_melted['Cell_Type'].str.replace(r'\d+', '')

# Grouping by Gene and Cell_Type and calculating the mean
df_grouped = df_melted.groupby(['Gene', 'Cell_Type']).mean().reset_index()

# Pivoting back to wide format
df_pivot = df_grouped.pivot(index='Gene', columns='Cell_Type', values='Value').reset_index()


Thank you for your answer! I tweaked some of this code and it worked just how I was hoping it would
